# why am i seeing the close button twice when using cluetip

Tags: jquery, cluetip

I am using [jquery cluetip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/) and i have noticed taht in some cases the first time i click on an items it shows the CLOSE text twice, when i click a second time, it only shows it once.  So first time i see this:

[image]

and the second time i see this:

[image]

Has anyone seen this before? I have multiple cluetips on the page but can't see how that would be driving this.  Here is my cluetip javascript code:

```
 $('#myItem').cluetip({
    width: '500px',
    showTitle: false,
    topOffset: 25,
    leftOffset: 5,
    positionBy: 'bottomTop',
    cluetipClass: 'jtip',
    activation: 'click',
    hoverIntent: {
        sensitivity: 7,
        interval: 100,
        timeout: 500
    },
    sticky: true,
    mouseOutClose: true,
    ajaxSettings: {
        dataType: 'json'
    },
    ajaxProcess: function (data) {

        return data.Content;
    }
});
```

I see the error has been raised [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?674078-jquery-cluetip-plugin-problem-duplicate-close-buttons-showing) and [on this forum also](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/cluetip-plugin-problem-duplicate-close-buttons-showing), but i don't see any solution or suggestions given.

### Update:

Not sure if this is helpful but i capture the "double" situation in firebug and here is the html that gets produced.  As you can see, there are multiple elements with id="cluetip-close"

```
   <div id="cluetip-inner"><div id="cluetip-close"><a href="#">Close</a></div><div id="cluetip-close"><a href="#">Close</a></div>
```

I have debugged through the cluetip code and when I get multiple closes, I notice that when it hits this line:

```
  if (opts.sticky) {
    var $closeLink = $('<div id="cluetip-close"><a href="#">' + opts.closeText + '</a></div>');
```

the $cluetipInner already has the '

I still can't figure out what situation this happens in . . the only way i can reproduce it, is if I clear all my browser cache and then restart . . maybe some timing issue with the ajax callback?

Comment: Can you provide a JS Fiddle demo?

Comment: Have you tried using the `localIdSuffix: "-cluetip",` setting described [here](https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-cluetip/issues/15#issuecomment-427111)?

Comment: @hyperslug - my content isn't being duplicated . .just the Close text (which is part of the tooltip - not my content)

Comment: Can we see a demo where the code is running?

Comment: Can you post a demo of this issue?

Comment: Any chance your html has two elements with an id of myItem?

Comment: Please try the suggestions recommended [here](https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-cluetip/issues/15). It seems like this is a common issue with jquery-cluetip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this problem was bug and fixed. Here the fixes [close link was being inserted multiple times in some cases. Fixes #34](https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-cluetip/commit/5bc2966c30592a8a3448bdf764fdf9f13938726e)

Comment: yup . .turns out I was on an old version of the library. after upgrading, problem went away

Answer (score -2):

You can try this code:

```
$(function(){
$('.cluetip-close:eq(2)').remove();
});
```

This will remove the second instance of the close div

Comment: this seems like a hack  . .i am trying to figure out why it is showing in tne first place and prevent it from doing that

Comment: also, i now go into a situation where 3 show up so that answer above wouldn't solve that as well.  ULtimatley i want to find out why its happening in the first place